# C++11 (gcc 4.9): error at template function (converting tuple vector to single component vector)

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

when compiling following code with C++11 (gcc 4.9), I get a compiler error:

```
//converts tuple vector to single component vector
template<class In, class Out, int Idx>
QVector<Out> tuple_vector_to_member_vector (const QVector<In>& in_vector)
{
    QVector<Out> out_vector;
    for (In in : in_vector)
        out_vector.push_back(in.get<Idx>());
    return out_vector;
}
```

The error is as following (and occurs as well when the template is not instantiated):

```
 error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
     out_vector.push_back(in.get<Idx>());
```

(Visual C++ 2013 accepts it on the other hand.)

I guess that one have to place

```
typename In::get<Idx>
```

or similar in any form, but I don't know where.

Has someone an idea?

Thank you.

Comment: `in.template get<Idx>`

Comment: @Columbo you should post an answer rather than a comment, no matter how small it is.

Comment: afaik C++11 dropped the requirement to place template keyword before template member functions(I could be wrong tho), but yes, that is the problem

Comment: following code seems to be accepted by gcc 4.9:     out_vector.push_back(in.In::template get<Idx>());